# Web-Based Screen Recorder Plugin

Tags: java, php, python, browser, screen-recording

I want to start on a new project regarding screen recording from web browsers, probably using a plugin or something similar (if it is possible). Basically I need a web interface from where the user runs something like a plugin, select the area where the screencast should be, press the record button, talk for maximum 5 minutes then the video should be uploaded to my server for further review. (I am doing this for a school project where the students/users use this max 5min videos to tell the teacher about an issue/problem etc.). I've researched (Google it :D) about different methods that I can use. I am a student aswell and I have a limited amount of programming knowledge mostly with python, html, css, javascript, objective c & php but I am more then glad to learn something new if is required. I've found an open-source plugin called ScreenBird 
https://github.com/adamhub/screenbird
This is what I need but it requires from what I know a Python Server (correct me if I am wrong) which I don't have from the school. I can work only on a Apache server from where my issue, otherwise the ScreenBord should be enough. I don't want to go so much into programming the plugin because I want to work on the design of the website mostly for a better presentation. I really want to start working on this as soon as possible but now I am stuck on what tool to use and that's why I am writing this question: What is the best web-based screen recorder plugin for my needs?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For the Screen Installation instructions are given here: https://github.com/adamhub/screenbird/blob/master/README.md

I don't think you need a python server. You just need python installed.

You should be able to run it on localhost and local network, if you don't need it on the internet. Buying hosting for a python server might be useful in this case, its not too expensive :http://www.whoishostingthis.com/compare/python/#

You didn't mention what type of server you have access to, default could mean anything (Apache, IIS, TomCat etc)

Comment: I have access to a Apache Server as a school sub-domain where the project should be.